# pg_restore: [archiver] did not find magic string in file header

Tags: postgresql, backup, postgresql-9.1, pg-dump

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1 and want to restore backup files generated with `pg_dump`:

```
sudo pg_dump -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres --clean --inserts -E UTF8 -f out.sql database_name
```

This command generates a valid sql file that starts with droping any existing database objects, then generates all tables, indizes, sequences and so on, and finally inserts data.

When I try to restore the generated backup file with: (line breaks added for display purposes only)

```
sudo pg_restore 
    -d database_name -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres
    --format=c --clean --create out.sql
```

it fails and prints:

```
pg_restore: [archiver] did not find magic string in file header
```

What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You're restoring with `pg_restore --format=c ...` but the `pg_dump` was not done with `--format=c`, it was done with the default,  **plain** format.

From `pg_dump` manpage:

> ```
>   -F format, --format=format
>        Selects the format of the output.  format can be one of the
>        following:
>
>        p, plain
>            Output a plain-text SQL script file (the default).
> ```

A dump in plain format should be fed directly to the `psql` command-line tool, `pg_restore` doesn't know what it is, which is the reason of this error message: *did not find magic string in file header*.

You can look directly at the dump file with `more out.sql` in shell and you'll see readable SQL commands. Restore it with `psql -f out.sql [other options]`. You will probably want to create the target database first, as the `--create` option is not present in the `pg_dump` invocation.

On the other hand, you may reinvoke the dump adding `--format=c` to its options. Then that would be the opposite: `pg_restore` must be used to interpret a dump file in the custom format.

Comment: in my case I was importing the wrong file, it had similar name.. hope this comment will help someone someday

Answer (score 1):

One possible problem is your data file is truncated. Check to see if you're downloading the full file by comparing file sizes.

Answer (score 1):

If you use git-lfs, make sure to have the actual file, not the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering this error on Windows after making a backup and then immediately attempting to restore it. Turned out the issue was, I wrote the file out using `pg_dump ... > filename`, which apparently corrupts the output. Instead, I needed to write the file out using `pg_dump ... -f filename`. Once I had a backup file I'd created that way, it restored without incident.